# Node.js: extracting data from form and submitting to Mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Using Node and Express. How would I go about saving all the `request` data to an array, and then insert each item from the array to a mongo collection?

My route is currently setup like this: `app.post("/addbulletin", routes.addbulletin(db));`

And I'm handling the view and processing the data like so:

```
exports.addbulletin = function(db) {
  return function(req, res) {

    // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    var date = req.body.date,
        name = req.body.name;
        // and many more...

    // Submit to the DB
    collection.insert({
      "date" : date,
      "name" : name
      // and many more...
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
      }
      else {
        res.location("index");
        res.redirect("/");
      }
    });

  }
}
```

The problem with this way is that I have to know all of the items that need sent to the database. What if I don't know what fields will be on a page to grab the data from? That's exactly the situation I'm in currently, because I have a form that's populating inputs based upon a user selection. So I don't want to have to put every single possible `req.body.whatever` in a variable. I'd instead want to just say `req.body.all`, for example, and save just the data that was submitted to variables, then insert those into the database, extracting the name for each field too, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the `req.body` to mongodb directly:

```
// Submit to the DB
collection.insert(req.body, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
  }
  else {
    res.location("index");
    res.redirect("/");
  }
});
```

Just persist the req.body object. Keep in mind to filter (delete) some properties like `_id`:

```
delete req.body.__id
```

Comment: Oh nice, thank you! Curious though, is there a reason I'd want to delete the id?

Comment: You may want to delete the `_id` field to avoid that malicious users post data to your handler that under certain circumstances may change existing documents.